# Search multiple words in a string + java

Tags: java

I have 10 pages of txt file, in which I have to search a series of 10,000 words to check how many words exists in the file content.

I am using AhoCorasic algorithm for search. However to check if each word exists or not, I have add 10,000 terms to the list. That is I have to iterate 10,000 times to know if each word exists. (10,000 can grow to n)

Problems with above approach are --> CPU boosts as it has to loop 10,000 times and Time it takes to complete the task is more.

I am looking at alternative approach, where I can give all 10,000 words at a time ( to avoid looping) and get the result for each word.

Is there a way to implement this. Or if there is any other alternative to Ahocorasic search to achieve above scenario.

Comment: Apache Lucene. Your bottleneck is going to be in I/O not CPU IMHO.

Comment: If the file is the same for each such search, simply make an index that contains each word in that file and its respective position. Keep this index in a file and simply load it every time you need to search...

Comment: Create a Map of the words to their number of occurrences, initialized to 0. The algorithm can then get a word from the txt file, get the corresponding number of occurrences from the map and increment it by 1 if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

Invert the search: create a Set of the words in the text, then looking up whether a term is in the source material is O(1). Still, as others have suggested, if you need to do more complex matching than simple term existence, I'd also recommend using Lucene.